# How to get code library targetting .Net 4 to work with .Net 3.5 application

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, interop

I'm building a new code library and would like to use .Net 4 as my target framework as all my new apps will use .net 4. My legacy web apps use .Net 3.5. I want to use this code library for all of my apps.

At this point, I see only 2 options

1. Compile the dll for each framework I need, changing the target framework each time
2. Create separate projects with differing target frameworks.

Is there any way around this so my code library is a single compile? Didn't know if there was something built into 4 to allow something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just build your libraries against .NET 3.5?

- If they're trying to use .NET 4 features then obviously they won't work against your .NET 3.5 webapps anyway
- If they're not, then using .NET 3.5 should be fine

There are some caveats around interop and mixed-mode assemblies, but for pure-C# assemblies it shouldn't be a problem.

It's *possible* to have different build configurations targeting different versions of the framework, but a bit of a pain - you'll need to mess with the project files manually. See the project files for [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) as an example.

I don't see why you were happy with the .NET 2 / .NET 3.5 situation before - it's not very significantly different to that.

Of course, updating your webapps to run on .NET 4 would probably be the best solution, going forward.

Comment: It's a DAL and I was hoping to use EF4.

Comment: @asp316: Then how were you expecting it to work from .NET 3.5?

Comment: @Skeet - I didn't think it would work. Figured I'd ask if there was an interop trick to allow something like this to work to hold me over until my web apps are upgraded to net4.

Comment: @asp316: But you claimed you were fine with .NET 3.5 and .NET 2 - how would you try to make a .NET 2 app use a .NET 3.5 API?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Jon, I think we're misunderstanding each other. My apps are .Net 3.5. I want to use .net4 features (EF entities while mapping POCOs) in a class library I want to reference. As you pointed out, that's not possible. That's what I was needing.

When I wrote about .Net2,3,and 3.5, I was solely speaking about them being based on the same core framework and upgrading your app was easy and relatively painless. I wasn't inferring my apps were .net2 using 3.x APIs. My statement there is unclear.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @asp316: .NET 2/3/3.5 used the same CLR, but the change to use CLR 4 is unlikely to have very much impact on you. Upgrading an app to .NET 4 should be no harder than upgrading from 2 to 3.5, for *most* apps.